# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_escape_string() in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have wordpress with woocommerce, for some reason my site is not working after I updated the site, and I'm getting:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_escape_string()
```

I enabled the debug in wordpress, and it says:

```
fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_escape_string() in /home/homedirecty/mysite.ca/wp-content/themes/resca-child/functions.php:60
```

```php
if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_escape_string( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
    {
        $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'"');
```

my site does not work.

---

EDIT: now I'm getting this error:

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/root/ba.mysite.ca/wp-content/themes/resca-child/functions.php on line 60

So I updated as the following: here is the line 60

```
if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysqli_escape_string( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
{
    $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'"');
    if ($data -> full_content)
        {
            print stripslashes($data -> content);
        }
    else
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer this question.

`mysql_escape_string` is deprecated.

Please use `mysqli_escape_string()` instead of use it.

For further information go to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php.

I hope my answer is okay for you.

Comment: I'm getting an error, can please check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_escape_string-is part of old deprecated MySQL extension. The extension is no longer available in PHP >= 7.0 and hence the error. Your theme needs to be updated.

Just to fix the particular issue, you can use the Wordpress function [wpdb::_real_escape()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/_real_escape/) instead.